# How to check NDK error log in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk

I meet some NDK error log like that:

- SIGSEGV (signal SIGSEGV: invalid address (fault address:
- 0x7f5479d281)) Signal: SIGSEGV (signal SIGSEGV: invalid address (fault address: 0x10))
- Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x18

According to the [offical documents](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-stack.html), I use ndk-stack to deal the NDK logs. But it does't show the detail line like /tmp/foo/crasher/jni/foo.c:9, I guess it might be the cause of the closed source library.

So I would like to know how to deal with this situation is more appropriate? Thanks very much.

Comment: paste actual stack trace then someone can help you too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, ndk-stack should indeed be the tool to achieve what you need.

I would suggest trying to detect the exact line in your code that causes the problem by putting some log lines along your code. And make sure you run the ndk in debug configuration (APP_OPTIM := debug in Application.mk)